# iOS Custom URL scheme doesn't show account

Tags: salesforce1-app, custom-url

I’m trying to launch Salesforce1 using the documented custom URL scheme.  The Salesforce1 app opens, but it does not navigate to the given account.  Do we have a support contact we can work with on issues like these?

Here’s the example URL:

salesforce1://sObject/001L000000cpJHEIA2/view

I verified the salesforce account id is correct and the URL format matches what’s documented.  Any thoughts as to what the account view does not display.  I'm using a sandbox environment and V7.0.1 of Salesforce1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url scheme I use is actually:

```
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=[Account Id]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Works like a charm.  I'm a bit puzzled though because I was basing my URL on a Salesforce PDF titled "Salesforce1 for iOS Mobile URL Schemes", dated November 2014.  The URL schemes there look nothing like what you have above!  The link to the document is https://success.salesforce.com/06930000003vIt6.

Comment: Yeah...I'm not sure where they came up with those schemes. I guess it might depend on what version you have installed and on what device (iPad, etc).